# Kafka messages not writen to parquet file until the latest offset is reached

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I would like to read a Kafka topic and write to a parquet or delta file and be able to read from that parquet file before all of the messages in the Kafka topic have been read. I had this working, but then I made a change and now it I have to wait until all messages have been consumed before there is anything in the parquet file. My code is below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object MinimalTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("MinimalTest")
      .getOrCreate()

    val kafkaBrokers = "localhost:9092"
    val topic = "FakeTopic"

    val startingOffsets = "earliest"

    val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
      .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .load()

    val path = "<dir>/MinimalTest"
    val checkpointLocation = "<dir>/CheckpointMinimalTest"

    df.writeStream
      .format("parquet")
      .outputMode("append")
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
      .option("path", path)
      .start()

    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
  }
}
```

I haven't found anyone with the same problem and I haven't found a solution by reading relevant documentation. I think someone told me to commit. I tried setting "enable.auto.commit" to true, but then I got an error message saying that "enable.auto.commit" is not supported.

I am using Spark.2.4.4

Comment: fbad gave the answer before I saw your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of offsets processed per trigger by setting `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` in Kafka source option ([Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)):

```
val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
      .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets)
      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .load()
```

If `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` is not defined, latest offset will be used as you can see in [Spark 2.4.4 code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSource.scala#L153).

Comment: That works. Thanks. I tried to up vote your answer, but I am new here and don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)